# Java garbage collection confusion

Tags: java, garbage-collection

If I have a long-lasting object A and lots of temporary objects B, C, D, etc. which contain a reference to A, will those temporary objects ever be collected as long as A is referenced by something?

```
class A {} // (sits in web app session)

class B {
  private A a;
}

class C {
  private A a;
}
```

Where B and C exist for the request only, but contain references to A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will, if there is no way to reach B and C (but they reach other objects) they will be collected as usual.

Answer (score 4):

B and C can be garbage collected imediately after the request. Nothing refers to them.

Comment: No, they *can* be collected immediately, it's not imperative.

Comment: If they are in the request scope the request will have a reference to them. when it becomes unreachable so do they. Note that the poster says they "exist for the request"

Comment: The garbage collector doesn't clear memory right away, they **can** be collected, it doesn't mean they **will** be collected at that time.

Comment: Precisely. Nothing says the GC must run after every request, or worse, every time an object might have become unreachable (it would be horribly inefficient if it was required).

Comment: I don't think *I* said otherwise? did you comment on the wrong answer?

Comment: I am moderately sure your answer used to say *will* (and either @MaurícioLinhares can't read either, or agrees). The current wording is, of course, correct; if it was there from the beginning, I am indeed mistaken and very sorry.

Comment: Honestly I didn't edit it, though I don't know if someone else did :) certainly what it says now is what I *meant* to say :)

Comment: Then I apologize :) Maybe I'm just sleepy (it's getting late over here).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can be collected. If A held a reference to them, then they wouldn't be collected as long as A is still reachable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they will. Garbage collection keeps objects alive as long as they are reachable from the root reachable objects (basically local variables in currently active calls, plus globals).

If `A` contains no references to the `B` and `C` objects, then it can't keep them alive; the fact that `A` is referenced *by* the `B` and `C` objects is irrelevant.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for the rare joy of seeing a 100% correct retelling of the workings of the GC.